# How to use Union or Intersect instead of an OR in my Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The query below works, but from what I've read, the `OR` in the `JOIN` is not the most efficient way to get my results.  I think that maybe I should be using a `UNION` or `INTERSECT`, but I can't figure out how to accomplish that.  Can someone explain the 'proper' what to get my results?

```
WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT SC, SN, COUNT(AL) AS UNEXCUSED 
              FROM ATT 
              WHERE AL = 'U' 
              GROUP BY SC, SN),
     CTE2 AS (SELECT SC, SN, COUNT(AL) AS SUSPENDED 
              FROM ATT 
              WHERE AL = 'S' 
              GROUP BY SC, SN) 
SELECT STU.ID, STU.SC, STU.SN, 
       ISNULL(CTE1.UNEXCUSED, '') AS UNX,
       ISNULL(CTE2.SUSPENDED, '') AS SUS 
FROM CTE2
FULL JOIN CTE1 
       ON CTE1.SC = CTE2.SC 
          AND CTE1.SN = CTE2.SN
JOIN STU 
  ON (CTE1.SC = STU.SC 
      AND CTE1.SN = STU.SN) 
     OR (CTE2.SC = STU.SC 
         AND CTE2.SN = STU.SN)
WHERE STU.SC IN (1,2,4,9,11,15)
```

This is a sample of the output:

```
ID      SC  SN     UNX  SUS
4291432 15  602    0    8
4296250 15  688    6    3
4216462 15  695    0    12
4916602 15  623    0    2
4295193 1   150    1    0
4215874 2   216    1    0
4005707 15  297    1    0
```

Thank you.

Comment: When two queries mean the same thing, a decent DBMS will tend to execute them in the same way, even if they use different syntax. So just rewriting the query syntax without changing the meaning of the query is unlikely to produce any difference in performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd change your query around like this:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT SC, SN, COUNT(AL) AS UNEXCUSED 
              FROM ATT 
              WHERE AL = 'U' 
              GROUP BY SC, SN),
     CTE2 AS (SELECT SC, SN, COUNT(AL) AS SUSPENDED 
              FROM ATT 
              WHERE AL = 'S' 
              GROUP BY SC, SN) 
SELECT STU.ID, STU.SC, STU.SN, 
       ISNULL(CTE1.UNEXCUSED, '') AS UNX,
       ISNULL(CTE2.SUSPENDED, '') AS SUS 
FROM STU
LEFT JOIN CTE1
       ON (CTE1.SC = STU.SC 
           AND CTE1.SN = STU.SN) 
LEFT JOIN CTE2 
       ON (CTE2.SC = STU.SC 
           AND CTE2.SN = STU.SN)
WHERE STU.SC IN (1,2,4,9,11,15)
```

.... If for no other reason than it makes your intended results a little more clear.  Note that the optimizer may still generate the same explain plan.